Plotting time intervals in R and tiling for several years
I am currently trying to plot the effort in sampling for my masters thesis, which looks something similar to this:
Figure 1:

So i have data for 3 years, and i want to reflect the exact days of the month when each deployment started and finished. But in R, i only manage to plot the following:
Figure 2:

The thing is, i would like my plot to show only the 12 months in the x axis and overlap the years on the y axis, so that the figure is "slimmer". I am guessing i have to somehow take out the year of the POSIXct dates, but i do not manage to represent the intervals as precisely then.
I did a subset of my data for this question and my script looks like this:
library(ggplot2)      
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Deployment3 <- seq(from = as.Date("2021-12-15"), to = as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "day"); 
deploy3 <- data.frame(count=1:length(Deployment3)); 
deploy3$day <- Deployment3; 
deploy3$year <- format(Deployment3, "%Y");  
deploy3$id <- "Deployment 3"
deploy3$start <- as.Date("2021-12-15"); deploy3$end <- as.Date("2021-12-31"); 

Deployment7 <- seq(from = as.Date("2022-12-17"), to = as.Date("2022-12-31"), by = "day"); 
deploy7 <- data.frame(count=1:length(Deployment7)); deploy7$day <- Deployment7; 
deploy7$year <- format(Deployment7, "%Y");  deploy7$id <- "Deployment 7";
deploy7$start <- as.Date("2022-12-17"); deploy7$end <- as.Date("2022-12-31");

Deployment7b <- seq(from = as.Date("2023-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-01-31"), by = "day"); 
deploy7b <- data.frame(count=1:length(Deployment7b)); deploy7b$day <- Deployment7b; 
deploy7b$year <- format(Deployment7b, "%Y");  deploy7b$id <- "Deployment 7"
deploy7b$start <- as.Date("2023-01-01"); deploy7b$end <- as.Date("2023-01-31")

deployments <- bind_rows(deploy3,deploy7,deploy7b)
deployments$start <- as.Date(deployments$start)
deployments$end <- as.Date(deployments$end)

ggplot(deployments) + 
geom_tile(aes(x = start, y = as.factor(year), width = end - start), height = 0.4) +
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "1 month", expand = c(0, 0)) +  
labs(x = "Month", y = "Year") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

If somebody would have any idea or suggestion to make the fig.2 more similar to fig.1 would be great.
Thank you and cheers!

How would you want to treat ranges that span two calendar years? Should it be shown as two ranges, and if so, should those appear in the same row or should they appear in the row each subset belongs to?

Yes, I am treating them as separate ranges because to organize them by year (that's why there is Deployment7b).

I've used line segments that I group by year and in this case, deployment, so they can span multiple years, my x axis is the day of the year, with months as labels:
library(ggplot2)      
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(
  ~start, ~end,
  "2021-09-25", "2021-11-08",  
  "2021-11-16", "2021-11-30",
  "2021-12-08", "2022-01-02",
  "2022-04-15", "2022-06-07",
  "2022-08-15", "2022-11-30",
  "2022-12-15", "2023-01-20",
  "2023-02-15", "2023-04-07",
  "2023-07-07", "2023-08-14",
  "2023-08-15", "2023-09-30",
  "2023-10-10", "2023-11-30"
  )  |> 
  mutate(deployment = paste0("D", row_number())) |>
  mutate(across(start:end, ymd)) |>  
  reframe(day = seq.Date(start, end, "day"), .by = c(deployment, start, end)) |>  
  mutate(year = year(day),
         yday = yday(day),
         group = paste(year, deployment, sep = "_")
         )

tail(df)

ggplot(data = df) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = yday, 
    y = year, 
    group = group, 
    color = deployment
  ),
  alpha = .5,
  linewidth = 12)+
  scale_y_reverse(
    breaks = sort(unique(df$year)), 
    limits = rev(range(unique(df$year)) + c(-.8, .8))
  )+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = yday(seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-15"), to = as.Date("2021-12-15"), by = "month")),
    labels = month.abb,
    position = "top"
  )+
  labs(x = "", y = "")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/4,
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "grey95", linewidth = .5),
  )


Shorter alternative for creating the table: tribble(~start, ~end, ~name, "2021-09-25", "2021-11-08", "D1",  "2021-11-16", "2021-11-30", "D2") |> mutate(across(start:end, ymd)) |>  reframe(day = seq.Date(start, end, "day"), .by = c(name, start, end)) |>  mutate(year = year(day),  group = paste(year, name)) etc.

I've updated the answer with Jon's suggestion.

Yeah that was helpful and worked perfectly with my data. Thank you both!
